# " I thought I was the Glob of rap " What is the meaning of "glob" in this time?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, nouns

I saw this word in "*Adventure Time*" cartoon series.

Another instance of using this word --> "oh my glob"

Comment: Could it be a play on words in reference to [this character](https://adventuretime.fandom.com/wiki/Grob_Gob_Glob_Grod)?

Answer (score 2):

Its a joke, specific to that show.  In the show, expression in English that use the word "God" are changed to use the word "glob".

The word "glob" sounds like "god".  In fact, in the show there is a god-like being called [Grob Gob Glob Grod](https://adventuretime.fandom.com/wiki/Grob_Gob_Glob_Grod)

It's not used outside to the context of Adventure Time.